# Defining generic Result<T, E> as return type

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'd like to create a `trait` that forces the return type of `Result<T, E>` on some functions, but I cannot figure out the syntax to define this.

I've gotten as far as:

```
pub type NamedResult<T, E> = Result<T, E>;

pub trait Foo {
    fn bar<T, E>(&self) -> NamedResult<T, E>;
}

pub struct Thing;

impl Foo for Thing {
    pub fn bar<T, E>(&self) -> NamedResult<T, E> {
        Ok(78i32)
    }
}
```

Produces the following error:

```
error: mismatched types: 
    expected 'T', 
    found 'i32'
(expected type parameter, found i32) [E0308]
```

So I then tried:

```
pub fn bar<i32, String>(&self) -> NamedResult<i32, String> {
    Ok(78i32)
}
```

And received the following error:

```
error: user-defined types or type parameters cannot shadow the primitive types [E0317]
```

What would the proper syntax be so that I can force the implementer of said trait to return a `Result<T, E>` type on certain functions?

Comment: Why the `NamedResult`? That part is a complete red herring.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan it started out as `NamedResult<T> = Result<T, Error>`, but then I moved away from that once I got the first batch of errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fn bar<T, E>(&self) -> Result<T, E>;
```

This says that you have a function `bar` which, given arbitrary types `T` and `E`, will return a `Result<T, E>`. Remember that: *the user specifies the type*. But what the body of your method is doing is returning a `Result<i32, _>`, but `i32` is not `T`.

If *you* wish to specify the type that will be returned, that needs to be specified on the trait implementation, either as a generic or (more normally) as an associated type:

```
pub trait Foo {
    type Bar;
    type BarError;

    fn bar(&self) -> Result<Self::Bar, Self::BarError>;
}

pub struct Thing;

impl Foo for Thing {
    type Bar = i32;
    type BarError = ();

    pub fn bar(&self) -> Result<i32, ()> {
        Ok(78i32)
    }
}
```

This way, the user is not specifying the type; rather, when you know that you are calling the `bar` method on a `Thing`, you know that the output type will be `Result<i32, ()>`.

Comment: What would it look like to implement the trait so that with `Result<T, E>`, the types could be whatever the user wants? Or is it not possible to specify it must return a Result, only a type-defined Result?

Comment: Ultimately, the compiler has to know how big the return type is. Functions must have a return type known at compile time.

Comment: @nathansizemore: “whatever the user wants” simply doesn’t make sense as a concept. Your code must somehow produce a value of whatever type—how is it going to do so?

Comment: Well I had this rather dumb idea of allowing a user to initialize my library by way of callback, which one would be an error callback, and when an error occurred I would pass that error into the error callback. Using the method above, it could be used for any type of error or return value, but now that you've pointed this out, I can see how non-useful it actually would be.